# Quarkus Bulkhead metrics 'ft_bulkhead_executionsRunning' and 'ft_bulkhead_executionsWaiting' NaN

Tags: quarkus

I have a Reactive REST endpoint annotated with @Bulkhead.

'ft_bulkhead_executionsRunning' and 'ft_bulkhead_executionsWaiting' do NOT provide a value (NaN). I am NOT sure if this a BUG or maybe I am doing something wrong

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/ncudr-gud-dr/v1/directory-data/q/metrics | grep ft_bulkhead_
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /ncudr-gud-dr/v1/directory-data/q/metrics HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/openmetrics-text; version=1.0.0; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 65979
< 
{ [65979 bytes data]
# TYPE ft_bulkhead_calls counter
1# HELP ft_bulkhead_calls  
0ft_bulkhead_calls_total{bulkheadResult="rejected",method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} 120696.0
0ft_bulkhead_calls_total{bulkheadResult="accepted",method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} 210840.0
 65979 # TYPE ft_bulkhead_waitingDuration_seconds summary
 # HELP ft_bulkhead_waitingDuration_seconds  
1ft_bulkhead_waitingDuration_seconds_count{method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} 210840.0
0ft_bulkhead_waitingDuration_seconds_sum{method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} 7047.583918116
0 # TYPE ft_bulkhead_waitingDuration_seconds_max gauge
65# HELP ft_bulkhead_waitingDuration_seconds_max  
9ft_bulkhead_waitingDuration_seconds_max{method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} 0.363759962
79    0# TYPE ft_bulkhead_executionsRunning gauge
 # HELP ft_bulkhead_executionsRunning  
   ft_bulkhead_executionsRunning{method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} NaN
 0# TYPE ft_bulkhead_executionsWaiting gauge
 # HELP ft_bulkhead_executionsWaiting  
 ft_bulkhead_executionsWaiting{method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} NaN
10.0M      0 --:# TYPE ft_bulkhead_runningDuration_seconds summary
-# HELP ft_bulkhead_runningDuration_seconds  
-ft_bulkhead_runningDuration_seconds_count{method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} 210840.0
:ft_bulkhead_runningDuration_seconds_sum{method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} 21331.330171846
-# TYPE ft_bulkhead_runningDuration_seconds_max gauge
-# HELP ft_bulkhead_runningDuration_seconds_max  
 ft_bulkhead_runningDuration_seconds_max{method="org.cheva.ngud.SearchResource.query"} 0.578839078
```

Comment: To complement @Bulkhead is working fine, only metrics are missing

Using Quarkus 3.1.2

Comment: That sounds like a bug, though I'm not exactly sure where. Do you use MicroProfile Metrics or Micrometer? I assume it's Micrometer, because that uses `double` for all numerical values, and NaN is a floating point value. I don't see anything in the Micrometer metrics adapter that could cause this however. Do you possibly have a reproducer you could share?

Comment: I am using Micrometer.

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>


Yeah I can try to build a basic reproducer

Comment: That would be great, thanks!

Comment: You can easily reproduce with a REST endpoint like this

```
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Bulkhead(value = 1)
    public Uni<String> hello() {
        return Uni.createFrom().item("Hello from RESTEasy Reactive");
    }
}
```
and then using wrk tool to generate many concurrent requests (e.g. wrk -c 100  -d 5  http://localhost:10001/hello).

Comment: OK, the issue is that Micrometer by default holds a weak reference to the state object behind the gauge, which is something I didn't notice when implementing Micrometer support in SmallRye Fault Tolerance. Will fix soon.

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/34215 FYI